# JavaScript equivalent of Python's __setitem__

Tags: javascript, python, syntactic-sugar

```
var obj = {}
obj.__setitem__ = function(key, value){
  this[key] = value * value
}
obj.x = 2  // 4
obj.y = 3  // 9
```

JavaScript doesn't have __setitem__ and this example obviously doesn't work.

In python [__setitem__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) works like:

```
class CustomDict(dict):
  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    super(CustomDict, self).__setitem__(key, value * value)

d = CustomDict()
d['x'] = 2  # 4
d['y'] = 3  # 9
```

Is it possible to implement __setitem__ behavior in JavaScript? All tricky workarounds would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but there are plans for supporting a similar feature in JavaScript 2. The following object literal syntax has been suggested on [Mozilla bug 312116](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312116) and it seems that it might be how it will be done for object literals:

```
({
  get * (property) {
    // handle property gets here
  }
})
```

I'm assuming set would also be supported (as `set * (property, value) {...}`).

Comment: Looks nice! Could you post a link to the page there it was suggested?

Comment: @NV: It's in some bug on bugzilla.mozilla.org. I couldn't find it with some simple searches so it may take you a while to find it.

Answer (score 10):

> Is it possible to implement __setitem__ behavior in JavaScript?

No. There is no getter/setter for arbitrary properties in JavaScript.

In Firefox you can use JavaScript 1.5+'s getters and setters to define `x` and `y` properties that square their values on assignment, eg.:

```
var obj= {
    _x: 0,
    get x() { return this._x; },
    set x(v) { this._x=v*v; }
};
obj.x= 4;
alert(obj.x);
```

but you would have to declare a setter for each named property you wanted to use in advance. And it won't work cross-browser.

Answer (score 5):

you can do this (as objects in javascript are also associative arrays):

```
var obj = {};
obj._ = function(key, value){
  this[key] = value * value;
}
obj._('x', 2);  // 4
obj._('y', 3);  // 9

alert(obj.x + "," + obj.y); //--> 4,9
```

Comment: Yes, I can. But Python's __setitem__ much more prettier.

Comment: Oh, I see the irony. How can you implement obj.x+=2 or something like this?

Answer (score 5):

There are no true setters and getters in the commonly implemented Javascript versions, so if you want to emulate the effect you have to use some different syntax. For a property `obj.x`, using `obj.x()` to access the value of the property and `obj.x(123)` to set the value seems like a rather convenient syntax.

It can be implemented like this:

```
// Basic property class
function Property(value) {
   this.setter(value);
}

Property.prototype.setter = function(value) {
   this.value = value * value;
}

Property.prototype.getter = function() {
   return this.value;
}

Property.prototype.access = function(value) {
   if (value !== undefined)
      this.setter(value);
   return this.getter();
}


// generator function to add convenient access syntax
function make_property(value) {
   var prop = new Property(value);
   function propaccess(value) {
      return prop.access(value);
   }
   return propaccess;
}
```

Now properties generated by `make_property` support the desired syntax and square values they are assigned:

```
var obj = {
   x: make_property(2)
};

alert(obj.x()); // 4
obj.x(3);       // set value
alert(obj.x()); // 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can override the `[]` operator in the current version of JavaScript.  In current JavaScript, objects are largely just associative arrays, so the `[]` operator just adds a key/value pair to an array that is the object.

You could write methods that set specific values or even squared a number and added the value as a key/value pair but not by overloading the `[]` operator.

JavaScript2 has some specifications for operator overloading, but that spec is MIA.